# Смена ориентации страницы во время печати

Tags: печать, c++

Добрый день.

Необходимо менять ориентацию странички на принтере во время печати. 1-ая страничка портретная, 2-ая альбомная,... итд. Вариант альбомные переворачивать в портретные путем rotate(90) не подходит. Так как если будет печаться в pdf (виртуальный принтер) документ будет повернут. Office умеет менять ориентацию на лету и все хорошо получается. У меня найти рабочий пример не получилось и не получилось его написать (путем замены `DevMode->dmOrientation=DMORIENT_LANDSCAPE` после `EndPage`).

Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В качестве идеи. Вы можете попробовать печатать документ постранично, прерываясь после каждой страницы, выставляя новую ориентацию для оставшегося документа, и начиная печатать заново с места останова.